# Advanced PHP Directory With JSON Output

Tags: php, json

I'm currently working on a PHP script, that I can use for my mobile app, to connect to our server and get JSON data as a response of the connection.

I have created a very simple PHP directory which will output JSON as the response:

```
<?php

// An array of the file names
$directory = array();

//Open directory
$dir = opendir("./");

//List files in directory
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
{
    $directory[] = $file;
}
closedir($dir);

echo json_encode($directory);
?>
```

However, I am looking (if possible) to get more functionality out of this script but as I am relatively new to PHP, I am not entirely sure how I would go about getting the data I would like to use:

- file name
- file type
- file size
- date/time modified
- date/time created
- user that created the file
- url to the file

Would it also be possible to somehow identify whether the response was a file or a folder? As `..` would go to another directory & assign an id to each outputted file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### file name

You've already got that in your $file variable

#### file type

Depends on what you mean by file type, but you can get (guess) the MIME type using `mime_content_type($file)` (n.b. this function is deprecated) or better ye the FileInfo PECL extension (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php).

#### file size

Use the `stat()` function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php).

```
$info = stat($file);
echo "File size: " . $info['size'];
```

#### date/time modified

Again use `stat()`:

```
$info = stat($file);
echo "Last modified: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $info['mtime']);
```

Or with `filemtime()`:

```
echo "Last modified: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", filemtime($file));
```

#### date/time created

Use `filectime()` (Gets inode change time of file). On Windows this will return the created time, on Linux it will return the change time (most Linux file systems don't record a created time).

```
$ctime= filectime($file);
echo "Created: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $ctime);
```

#### user that created the file

On Linux you can get the file owner via `fileowner()`:

```
$owner_id = fileowner($file);
```

Or again via the versatile `stat()` function:

```
$info = stat($file);
$owner_id = $info['uid'];
```

Similar functions exist to get the group of the file.

#### url to the file

That will depend entirely on how you are exposing your files, however the `realpath()` function might prove useful (http://php.fubra.com/manual/en/function.realpath.php).

Comment: Those functions work perfectly (and I made relevant adjustments to get the URL of the file); so thanks for that! I'm looking at categorizing the JSON so that it's easier to get each component through my app. However, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but the 'items' component gets created for each file (http://codeshare.io/aOO0C) and results in an error when putting the response through a JSON parser (http://snag.gy/KCv9F.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Helped on the BlackBerry Support Formums: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/Securing-QFtp/m-p/3113418/highlight/true#M73468 so now the JSON isn't returning multiple instances of 'items'